# Is there a way to find out when some web page was made?

Tags: internet, date

*Nope, it's a fine title ...*

Is there a way to find out when some web page was made ?

(Example: I often, before buying equipment, search through reviews ... before shortening the list of "candidates" ... and, as Internet is such, I often find some thing that has very good reviews, but then, half an hour later, find out that that model is from 2 years ago ... alas, there was no date on the review page, so I thought, "it must be good" ... and it was for that time ... unfortunatelly, it isn't much nowadays).

Anyways, you realize the problem.

Is there a way to find ou when such a page was made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Wayback Machine might be the only way to tell when a page was created.  I know what you're talking about.  What I have done is go to [test freaks site](http://www.testfreaks.com/) and there they have a collection of "expert" and user reviews for the product I am looking for.  I can tell how fresh those reviews are from that one site.  I actually stumbled across it today.

Not sure if it helps you but hopefully it does, or others too..

Comment: test freaks are one of the bright stars in the review world, i agree.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very exacting, but sometimes I'll use [The Wayback Machine](http://www.archive.org/) to try to find when pages were created.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to find out the date, except asking the creator...

But I also think that every serious store shows the dates of when the reviews are made. And for a good journalism-style it is important to make the creation-date of an articel visible. Also for many products you will find a release-date at the manufacturers website or even wikipedia. With this information you should be able to see if a review is old or not. Also I didn't se a review from a product which will be released/made in the future yet :D